# What's the easiest way to get the headers from a CSV file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

All I need to do is get the headers from a CSV file.

file.csv is:

```
"A", "B", "C"  
"1", "2", "3"
```

My code is:

```
table = CSV.open("file.csv", :headers => true)

puts table.headers

table.each do |row|
  puts row 
end
```

Which gives me:

```
true
"1", "2", "3"
```

I've been looking at Ruby CSV documentation for hours and this is driving me crazy. I am convinced that there must be a simple one-liner that can return the headers to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like `CSV.read` will give you access to a `headers` method:

```
headers = CSV.read("file.csv", headers: true).headers
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
```

The above is really just a shortcut for `CSV.open("file.csv", headers: true).read.headers`. You could have gotten to it using `CSV.open` as you tried, but since `CSV.open` doesn't actually read the file when you call the method, there is no way for it to know what the headers are until it's actually read some data. This is why it just returns `true` in your example. After reading some data, it would finally return the headers:

```
  table = CSV.open("file.csv", :headers => true)
  table.headers
  # => true
  table.read
  # => #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2>
  table.headers
  # => ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: You can use `table.shift` (or `table.readline`) to read a single line before checking the headers, to avoid loading the entire file, if you have a very large file and only need the headers. If you want to start reading from the top of the file again after that, just use `table.rewind` to go back to the top.

Comment: This solution is not good, the OP wants the headers only, and eagerly loading/parsing the whole file is a waste of polar bears.

Answer (score 23):

In my opinion the best way to do this is:

`headers = CSV.foreach('file.csv').first`

Please note that its very tempting to use `CSV.read('file.csv'. headers: true).headers` but the catch is, `CSV.read` loads complete file in memory and hence increases your memory footprint and as also it makes it very slow to use for bigger files. Whenever possible please use `CSV.foreach`.
Below are the benchmarks for just a 20 MB file:

```
Ruby version: ruby 2.4.1p111 
File size: 20M  
****************
Time and memory usage with CSV.foreach:
Time: 0.0 seconds
Memory: 0.04 MB
****************
Time and memory usage with CSV.read:
Time: 5.88 seconds
Memory: 314.25 MB
```

A 20MB file increased memory footprint by 314 MB with `CSV.read`, imagine what a 1GB file will do to your system. In short please do not use `CSV.read`, i did and system went down for a 300MB file.

For further reading:
If you want to read more about this, [here](https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby) is a very good article on handling big files.

Also below is the script i used for benchmarking `CSV.foreach` and `CSV.read`:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'csv'
def print_memory_usage
  memory_before = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i
  yield
  memory_after = `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i
  puts "Memory: #{((memory_after - memory_before) / 1024.0).round(2)} MB"
end

def print_time_spent
  time = Benchmark.realtime do
    yield
  end
  puts "Time: #{time.round(2)} seconds"
end

file_path = '{path_to_csv_file}'
puts 'Ruby version: ' + `ruby -v`
puts 'File size:' + `du -h #{file_path}`
puts 'Time and memory usage with CSV.foreach: '
print_memory_usage do
  print_time_spent do
    headers = CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: false).first
  end
end
puts 'Time and memory usage with CSV.read:'
print_memory_usage do
  print_time_spent do
    headers = CSV.read(file_path, headers: true).headers
  end
end
```

Comment: Normally `CSV::foreach` is called with a block, in which case Ruby closes the file before exiting the block. When called without a block (in which case an enumerator is returned) do you know  when the file is closed? I've wondered about that for `IO::foreach`, which is more-or-less the same  
 issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a shorter answer then can try:

```
headers = CSV.open("file.csv", &:readline)
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: Good to know but I'd opt for the more explicit `.headers` approach that @Dylan-Markow suggests.